# Can Selenium be integrated with Team foundation server

Tags: selenium, tfs, selenium-webdriver, tfsbuild

I want to know whether Selenium can be integrated with Team foundation Server,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Anything that can be run as a Unit Test (whether using MSTest, NUnit, XUnit, etc) can be run via a TFS Build.

Also the Coded UI Test framework from Microsoft uses Selenium under the covers to provide cross-browser support.  Coded UI Tests can be run from TFS Builds like any other unit test.  The can also be tied to Test Cases and run via Remote Execution on Visual Studio Test Agents.